# how to restore win 10 if recovery image located in local drive C

Tags: windows-10, restore

i have moved to new laptop using 1tb external drive, there i included all my files and win 10 recovery image so i can restore settings as i was told. image (looks like folders 0_0)  is 90gb located in drive C.

i don't have access to any portable drives that big capacity anymore. cant find option to restore system from local drive. i wasn't able to find answer on google. advanced restart doesn't show option i needed

Comment: Windows Recovery does *not* create full disk image. It can only be used within Windows to help repair the OS. First install operating Windows.

Comment: Yes, always you need to the system image created using Windows backup to restore to a different hard drive. As you said, the old drive could restore the files. But you need to install OS.